# splitting flyway metatable schema_version and business data in two different databases possible?

Tags: flyway

It´s possible to configure flyway to use for the metatable (schema_version table) e.g. in PostgreSQL and for the migration scripts itself (mvn flyway:migrate) in another target database e.g. DB2?

The background of my question: 
Flyway don´t support DB2 z/OS. My idea was, flyway should track the history on PostgreSQL and migration itself on DB2 z/OS.

At the moment when i use DB2 z/OS i get this error:

```
FlywaySqlException:
[ERROR] Error retrieving the database user
[ERROR] ----------------------------------
[ERROR] SQL State  : 26501
[ERROR] Error Code : -514
[ERROR] Message    : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLH200C1, DRIVER=3.61.75
[ERROR] : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=CURRENT_USER, DRIVER=3.61.75
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

CURRENT_USER exists only in DB2 LUW variant.

Any workarounds or solution?